# How to delete folder with Delete Activity of Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to delete on-premises folder and all files in it.
I can successfully delete a file if I set file name to Filename.

However I was not able to remove folder with empty or * values in Filename.
Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deleting all files from folder:**

Create dataset parameters for folder and file path in the dataset and pass the values from the delete activity.

[image]

**Deleting folder itself:**

Create a dataset parameter for the folder name and pass the value from the delete activity. Do not create a file name parameter or pass any value in the file name in the dataset.

[image]